# How can i return Pivot table in sql server with column name?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have checked with the posted question that do pivot based on result not based on columns name 
can you please advice what should be sql script retrieving this result ?

Actual result

[image]

Expected result

[image: Expected Result]

Thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `union all`:

```
select 'name' as which,
       max(case when id = 1 then name end) as [1],
       max(case when id = 2 then name end) as [2],
       max(case when id = 3 then name end) as [3],
       max(case when id = 4 then name end) as [4]
from t
union all
select 'state' as which,
       max(case when id = 1 then state end) as [1],
       max(case when id = 2 then state end) as [2],
       max(case when id = 3 then state end) as [3],
       max(case when id = 4 then state end) as [4]
from t;
```

Comment: there would be 840 columns and i can not use like this

Comment: Then you need to create a stored procedure which creates this dynamically. You'd have a variable which you increment with +1 so that you'd have id=1, id=2 ... id=n. There is a nice tutorial for this approach: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/ and microsoft also provides some basic instruction here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql
Otherwise, the approach shown by Gordon Linoff is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Then, you can use a dynamic sql query.

**Query**

```
declare @sql as varchar(max);

select @sql = 'select '+ char(39) + 'name' + char(39) + ' as [id],' + 
stuff((select distinct ', max(case when [id] = ' 
   + cast([id] as varchar(100)) + ' then [name] end) 
      as [' + cast([id] as varchar(100)) + ']'
   from #t
   for xml path('')
), 1, 2, '') + 
' from #t union all ' +
'select '+ char(39) + 'state' + char(39) + ' as [id],' + 
stuff((select distinct ', max(case when [id] = ' 
   + cast([id] as varchar(100)) + ' then [state] end) 
      as [' + cast([id] as varchar(100)) + ']'
   from #t
   for xml path('')
), 1, 2, '') + 
' from #t';

exec(@sql);
```

Chanage `#t` according to yours.

Comment: I have 840+ columns and i can not write each of them individually inside your query is there any other way to get automatically columns name of result and iterate ?

Comment: @Rahul : Here you don't need to write them individually. It's dynamic. First try to use this query and then comment. Don't comment blindly.

Comment: Here you have used id and name static inside query that i dont need to put 
 ("max(case when [id] = '  + cast([id] as varchar(100)) + ' then [name] ").

Comment: @Rahul : Anyway it would be there in your result set right?

Comment: I have attached sample one i have 840+ columns. So i can not put 840 case inside a query which will impact on performance.

Comment: Then you may need to insert the result set into a temp table and then you can use the columns dynamically from `tempdb.sys.columns`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145455/discussion-between-wanderer-and-rahul).